# Statistics in properties different from statistics in attribute table (Arc)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, statistics

I have generic signed integer raster downloaded from the ORNL DAAC.

https://daac.ornl.gov/NACP/guides/NBCD_2000.html

It is a single band raster. I looked at the statistics in the properties of the raster i.e min, max, mean and std dev. I then calculated the statistics of the value column in the attribute table (by right clicking on the value header and choosing statistics). Why do both differ?

I have tried this with other rasters as well and do not know the reason.

Comment: presence of NoData?

Comment: @jbchurchill- No NoData raster values in the raster.

Comment: How much different? An example please.

Comment: They are different because each value in the table represents multiple cells given in Count field

Comment: Would the discussion at http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/25931/664 perhaps answer your question?   If not, please give explicit examples of the results you are getting so we can have a better idea of what's going on.  (There are other problems with ArcGIS statistics stemming from (a) precomputing them for rasters and (b) "sampling" the data to obtain approximations of the correct values).